# I need to find an image filter that ENHANCES punctiform noise

Tags: image, image-processing

I know of so many techniques to remove dirty like noise from images, but I am here with the opposite problem. I need to detect the presence of dirt like  components in an image. I have been searching for quite a while, but I cannot find any  filtering technique that would ENHANCE  such a pattern.

I imagine something like that should exist, after all astronomy seeks to enhance such things in deep space images as several medical imaging problems need to seek for calcifications, yet, I cannot find the name or description of any such technique. Can anyone point me into something like that?

Comment: You could always use one of the dirt removal/filtering techniques you allude to then difference the result with the original to just be left with the dirt.

Comment: In case you know how to remove the noise, you can do the following: **1.** Remove the noise. **2.** Get the "Noise image" by subtracting the "clean image" from the original image "N = clean_im - original_im". **3.** for enhancing the noise, sum the noise image N with the original image: "enhanced_noise_im = original_im + N". Do you really want to enhance the noise (or is it an intermediate stage)? Please post a sample image.

Comment: I want to enhance the noise , if present, because its presence signifies a different category to be predicted in the Convolutional Neural Netwowk I am training. The issue is,  certain calcification  in mammograms are benign most of the time, but the same calcification is a risk factor if there is dust like "noise" around it. This dust like noise is too weak most of the time for the AI to  learn about it, so I wanted to  enhance it .